# Progression of molecular dynamics simulation sizes

Tags: reference-request, molecular-dynamics

I'm looking for literature on the progression (year on year, or more fine-grained if possible) of Molecular Dynamics simulation sizes.

By simulation size I mean number of atoms, time step, total simulation time and the architecture it was executed on.

Bonus points if anyone knows of a similar database/list for consumer end hardware especially GPUs.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ask for a progression year-on-year or even more fine-grained is asking for a bit too much detail, I think. Available information is more coarse-grained. [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982210015289) reports a nine orders of magnitude progress in simulated timescales over three decades of molecular dynamics research on proteins in water.